# How to vectorize a for-loop numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, scikit-image

I'm fairly new to numpy, and currently unable to vectorize the for-loop in the following code:

```py
# Build an image_array by label discrimination, using seg and seg_4col, expanding discrimated labels in the process to fillflood the image
# lab arg being one of the 4 labels of the 4 colored seg (seg_4col)
def img_4c_d(lab, img):

    seg_islands = np.where(seg_4col == lab, seg, 0)
    seg_exp = expand_labels(seg_islands, distance=max(img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))

    unique_labels = unique(np.ravel(seg_exp))
    color_dic = np.zeros((np.max(unique_labels) + 1, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    for label in unique_labels:
        d = img[np.where(seg_islands == label)]

        color_dic[label] = [np.argmax(np.bincount(d[...,0])),
                            np.argmax(np.bincount(d[...,1])),
                            np.argmax(np.bincount(d[...,2]))]

    return color_dic[seg_exp]
```

`unique_labels` can hold thousands of values and you can easly guess how unperformant it is.

I tried all I could without sucess, If anyone can help, you are very thanked.

Comment: What are `seg` and function `unique()`?

Comment: @rajkumar_data `seg` is a 2D numpy array of positive int values (custom segmentation),   `unique()` is pandas's `pandas.unique` and just to tell `expand_labels` is from scikit-image  `skimage.segmentation.expand_labels`

Comment: `where` is only as useful as its argument `seg_islands == label`.  With `broadcasting` it may be possible to test `seg_islands == unique_labels[..None's.]` to make a higher dimensional boolean array.

Comment: @hpaulj I will look up `broadcasting` more deeply then, thks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.find_objects`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.find_objects.html#scipy.ndimage.find_objects) to get a smaller bounding box around each label. The `find_objects` function does this with only one pass through the image. This will make grabbing the pixels for that label much faster, especially if your objects are compact:

```py
from scipy.ndimage import find_objects  # NEW

# Build an image_array by label discrimination, using seg and seg_4col, expanding discrimated labels in the process to fillflood the image
# lab arg being one of the 4 labels of the 4 colored seg (seg_4col)
def img_4c_d(lab, img):

    seg_islands = np.where(seg_4col == lab, seg, 0)
    seg_exp = expand_labels(seg_islands, distance=max(img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))

    unique_labels = unique(np.ravel(seg_exp))
    color_dic = np.zeros((np.max(unique_labels) + 1, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    bounding_boxes = find_objects(seg_islands)  # NEW

    for label in unique_labels:
        boxed = img[bounding_boxes[label]]  # NEW
        d = boxed[boxed == label]  # NEW; note np.where was redundant here

        color_dic[label] = [np.argmax(np.bincount(d[...,0])),
                            np.argmax(np.bincount(d[...,1])),
                            np.argmax(np.bincount(d[...,2]))]

    return color_dic[seg_exp]
```

Note: this is also how [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops) works, and you could use the `extra_properties=` argument there to achieve the same goal.

Comment: After some tweaking (`img` is `RGBA`) I came up with this: `d = img[bounding_boxes[label]][seg_islands[bounding_boxes[label]] == label]` and it's way way faster. I'm sure i can speed this even more, but I'm satisfied for now, thank you very much for the help!